# XAML Data Binding in a nested Grid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have created a nested grid in XAML, which currently looks like this:

```
<Grid x:Name="mainGrid" >        
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid Grid.Row="{Binding Row}" Grid.Column="{Binding Col}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="0.1*"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="0" FontWeight="Bold" TextDecorations="Underline"/>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Names}" Grid.Row="1"/>
    </Grid>

</Grid>
```

My aim is to populate 4 `Grids` that follow the template of the inner `Grid`. I have attempted this by using the following code behind:

```
List<Test> tests = new List<Test>();

for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
     for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
     {
          Test t = new Test();
          t.Title = i + "\t" + j;
          t.Row = i;
          t.Col = j;
          tests.Add(t);
     }
}

mainGrid.DataContext = tests;
```

And the class definition:

```
class Test
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int Row { get; set; }
    public int Col { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<string> Names
    {
        get
        {
            return new ObservableCollection<string>() { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J"};
        }   
    }
}
```

My thoughts here were that I'd have 4 objects with Row/Col definitions for each segment of the outer `Grid` definition (0,0 & 0,1 & 1,0 & 1,1). The inner `Grid` would serve as a template like an `ItemTemplate` in a `ListView`. However only the top (0,0) `Grid` is populated.

What steps should I take so that the inner `Grid` behaves like a template and all 4 `Grids` are created and populated?

Comment: You might consider actually using an ItemsControl with basically your current inner grid as the Item Template, and the current outer Grid as your ItemContainer template and feed your collection via itemsource.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `ItemsControl`, where `ItemsSource` is a list of `Test`, and populate `ItemsPanel` with outer `Grid` and `ItemTemplate` with inner `Grid`

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            </Grid>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentPresenter}">
            <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="{Binding Row}"/>
            <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="{Binding Col}"/>
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="0.1*"/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="0" FontWeight="Bold" TextDecorations="Underline"/>
                <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Names}" Grid.Row="1"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

and because `ItemsControl` will wrap item in `ContentPresenter` you need to move `Grid.Column` and `Grid.Row` bindings to `ItemContainerStyle`

**EDIT**

`ItemsControl` is most basic control to display list of something. Controls like `ListBox`, `ListView`, `ComboBox`, `DataGrid` and even `MenuItem` they all inherit from `ItemsControl` adding more functionality on top like selection or column view.

`ItemsPanel` defines how the general items' container will look, and `ItemTemplate` defines how each item in the collection will look.

Each `ItemsControl` will have its item container type. For `ListBox` it will be `ListBoxItem`, for `ListView` it will be `ListViewItem` and so on and for `ItemsControl` it's `ContentPresenter`. It's just a visual container where each item of the list is put as a content, and then - according to hierarchy [MSDN:  Remarks section](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentpresenter(v=vs.110).aspx) - transformed to visual. In the visual tree this container is direct child of the items panel so things list `Grid.Column` and/or `Grid.Row` must be set against it. Also for example for `ListBox` it's `ListBoxItem` that holds `IsSelected` property. And the way to change that container or get data of the container is via `ItemContainerStyle`.

Comment: Yea, like this... +1 for example.

Comment: Thank you. I've not heard of the ItemsControl control before, so  i'll do a little bit of research to understand this more.

Comment: `ItemsControl` is most basic control to display list of something. Controls like `ListBox`, `ListView`, `ComboBox`, `DataGrid` and even `MenuItem` they all inherit from `ItemsControl` adding more functionality on top like selection or column view

Comment: So just to clarify, `ItemsControl` hosts a collection, `ItemsPanel` defines how the general container will look, and `ItemTemplate` defines how each item in the collection will look? Could you explain why the Row and Column needs to be inside this `ItemsContainerStyle`? Appreciated.