# How to place CheckBoxes in different rows/columns within a ListBox in WPF?

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview, listbox, itemspaneltemplate

In my WPF desktop application, I have a ListBox that I would like to display with two rows and two columns (i.e., a 2x2 grid), with a Checkbox in each of the four row/column spots - my XAML code is below.  Note that I don't want to do any data binding.  The code below works, but what shows up is that all four CheckBoxes are right on top of each other, even though I've specified that they should be in different rows/columns.  Could someone point out what I'm doing wrong and how to correct the XAML?  Every example I've found on the internet is a data-bound example, and this needs to be without data-binding (i.e., explicit).

```
<ListBox Margin="0,0,10,10" Name="myListBox" Height="139" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="112" >
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        </Grid>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>

    <CheckBox Content="WCF"  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"/>
    <CheckBox Content="ASP.NET"  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>
    <CheckBox Content="Java"  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"/>
    <CheckBox Content="C+"  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"/>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: I'm afraid you cannot do that without binding. `ListBox` wraps items in `ListBoxItem` which becomes direct child of `ItemsPanel` and you can set `Grid.Column` and/or `Grid.Row` in `ItemsContainerStyle` via binding

Comment: Thanks.  I was using the ListBox because it's scrollable, if I want to add more rows.  Do you recommend switching to a ListView, DataGrid, or another control? (again, because I won't need data binding for these)

Comment: Then don't use `ListBox` and put your `Grid` in `ScrollViewer`

Comment: I think you're right about using the ScrollViewer.  But, so I can learn how to do it via binding, do you have a link to a simple example of how to do it via binding a List (using either ScrollViewer, ListBox, ListView, etc.)?

Comment: if you want to do it via binding check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32529533/1432140) answer for example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're misusing `ListBox`.  `ListBox` is an `ItemsControl` and you're not really dealing with bound items, so you should use a different control to achieve your solution.  Something like the following should work:

```
<ScrollViewer Height="50"
              HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    <WrapPanel Width="150">
        <CheckBox Name="Wcf"
                  Content="WCF"
                  Width="75" />
        <CheckBox Name="Asp"
                  Content="ASP.NET"
                  Width="75" />
        <CheckBox Name="Java"
                  Content="Java"
                  Width="75" />
        <CheckBox Name="WhatIsThis"
                  Content="C+"
                  Width="75" />
        <CheckBox Content="WCF"
                  Width="75" />
        <CheckBox Content="ASP.NET"
                  Width="75" />
        <CheckBox Content="Java"
                  Width="75" />
        <CheckBox Content="C+"
                  Width="75" />
        <!-- add as many items as you want -->
    </WrapPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

If you want the content to be scroll-able, then wrap a `ScrollViewer` around your `WrapPanel` and set height on it.

Proof:

[image]

Note: I highly advise you to use data binding whenever it is possible.

Comment: Thanks.  I was using the ListBox because it's scrollable, if I want to add more rows.  Do you recommend switching to a ListView, DataGrid, or another control? (again, because I won't need data binding for these)

Comment: @swabygw if you're trying to define a layout with hard-coded labels, you're best off not using anything that inherits from `ItemsControl` (like `ListBox`) unless you plan on adding items to the control from code-behind (should really just use data-binding, but I'm biased)

Comment: I think you're right about using the ScrollViewer.  But, so I can learn how to do it via binding, do you have a link to a simple example of how to do it via binding a List (using either ScrollViewer, ListBox, ListView, etc.)?

Comment: There are many MVVM/data-binding examples out there.  One of my more details examples of MVVM can be found in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33697460/adding-removing-rows-of-controls/33698431#33698431) question.  In short, you'd build a collection of options, bind that to the `ItemsControl.ItemsSource`, and define `ItemsControl.ItemTemplate` using a `DataTemplate`.  Maybe I'll write a detailed example if this answer is marked at the answer ;)